# I have a 50 amp breaker on the wall for my spa, can I come off of it to 30 amp RV service

Tags: electrical-distribution

I have a 50 amp breaker at my Spa, can I run a 10-2 w/g 130 feet to my RV and install a RV box with 30 amp breaker and a 30amp RV plug?

Comment: Are you keeping the Spa?

Comment: How much current does the spa draw? (nameplate load)

Answer (score 1):

No. The spa breaker is almost certainly sized for the spa's needs, and it wouldn't be appropriate to daisy-chain from it. You'd need to set up the new circuit as a subpanel with its own breaker in the spa box.

Comment: I am not keeping a Spa

Comment: Then you should probably update your question to explain that more clearly.